# JasaScript. Как найти и вывести факториал 10! с помощью while?

Tags: while, факториал

нужен простейший код для этого, пожалуйста

Comment: что именно непонятно? Что такое while или что такое факториал?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Код

Вот он:

```js
let x = 1;  // В x будет лежать ответ
let n = 10;

while(n) x *= (n--); // Вот и весь код

console.log(x);
```

### Принцип работы

#### Шаг первый - начало

Факториал - это результат умножения чисел от `1` до `n`
Код изначально выглядит так:

```js
for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++) x *= i;
```

#### Шаг второй - меняем направление

Затем, идём не по возрастающей (`1, 2, 3, 4 ... n`), а по убывающей (`n, n-1 ... 2, 1`):

```js
for(let i = n; i > 0; i--) x *= i;
```

#### Шаг третий - немного укорачиваем код

После этого, можно заменить `i > 0` на `i != 0` а затем и просто на `i` (при преобразование в логическое значение `0` преобразуется в `false`, всё остальное в `true`)
Также можно заметить, что `i--`  вернёт значение `i` до операции:

```
let i = 5;
console.log(i--); // => 5, i теперь = 4
console.log(i--); // => 4, i теперь = 3
```

Зная это можно упростить код:

```js
for(let i = n; i;) x *= (i--);
```

#### Шаг четвёртый - избавляемся от `i`

Потом можно заметить, что мы используем только в одном месте - `let i = n`
Почему бы тогда не использовать вместо `i` просто `n`?

```js
for(; n;) x *= (n--);
```

#### Шаг пятый - используем `while`

Ну, а потом заменить `for` на `while`

```js
while(n) x *= (n--);
```

> #### Важное замечание
>
> Если `n` придётся использовать где-то ещё в программе, придётся использовать код из третьего шага

Comment: красиво. молодец

Comment: Да, он работает. спасибо большое. но если тебе не трудно объяснить,, я не очень понимаю как именно код работает. почему он работает? как я должен был мыслить чтобы написать его, и как мыслил ты когда писал его. спасибо)

Comment: Всё, добавил объяснение.

Comment: @JavascriptDev > *Факториал - это результат умножения чисел от 0 до n* Вероятно, вы хотели написать *от 1 до n*?

Comment: @Евгений Спасибо. Да, я ошибся.

Comment: @JavascriptDev аа, понял. ну теперь все понятнее намного. Спасибо тебе большое, друг) Ты лучший.

Comment: @user396639 Спасибо 

Comment: Это. Просто. Афигенно.